# How to convert laserscan measurements of ROS into values of Occupancy grid?

Tags: python, mapping, ros

I'm trying to pass the measurements of laserscan message into an occupancy grid. Each time, i know the exact position of robot in map (x_pos_t, y_pos_t). I have already initialized an empty occupancy grid. So, when i run the code the first laserscan measurements are placed good in occupancy grid, when i rotate the robot, misaligned values are inserted. Can you help me to fix the problem?

```
def mapping(x_pos_t , y_pos_t, theta, scan_msg, map_msg):
    # convert laser scans to occupancy grid
    for i, dist in enumerate(scan_msg.ranges):
        if dist < scan_msg.range_max:
            x = int((x_pos_t + dist * math.cos(scan_msg.angle_min + i * scan_msg.angle_increment)) / map_msg.info.resolution)
            y = int((y_pos_t + dist * math.sin(scan_msg.angle_min + i * scan_msg.angle_increment)) / map_msg.info.resolution)
            if x >= 0 and xr < map_msg.info.width and y >= 0 and y < map_msg.info.height:
                map_msg.data[y * map_msg.info.width + x] = 100

    return map_msg
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understood your question correctly, but it seems like you are not taking into account the robot's orientation (theta) when placing the laser scan measurements into the occupancy grid. You should rotate the laser scans by the robot's orientation before inserting them into the map. Here's an updated version of your function with the rotation applied:

```py
import math

def mapping(x_pos_t , y_pos_t, theta, scan_msg, map_msg):
    # convert laser scans to occupancy grid
    for i, dist in enumerate(scan_msg.ranges):
        if dist < scan_msg.range_max:
            # Calculate the angle of the current laser scan measurement
            angle = scan_msg.angle_min + i * scan_msg.angle_increment + theta
            
            # Rotate the laser scan measurements by the robot's orientation (theta)
            x = int((x_pos_t + dist * math.cos(angle)) / map_msg.info.resolution)
            y = int((y_pos_t + dist * math.sin(angle)) / map_msg.info.resolution)

            if x >= 0 and x < map_msg.info.width and y >= 0 and y < map_msg.info.height:
                map_msg.data[y * map_msg.info.width + x] = 100

    return map_msg
```

This should help align the laser scan measurements with the occupancy grid when the robot is rotated.